# How do I find out what the WIC Model is from CISCO IOS?

Tags: networking, cisco, ios

How do I find out what the model number of a WIC is with an IOS command? In show interface all I get is 'Hardware is Fast Ethernet', I don't see anything under 'show hardware' either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another command that may work is `show diag`. It will tell you the type of WIC, but I don't think it started showing the actual WIC part numbers until IOS 12.2.

Answer (score 3):

```
router# show inventory [raw]
```

should also give the parts installed in a router.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following after entering privileged (enabled) mode:

```
show controllers
```

This should tell you more about the hardware then you would ever care to know :)

Comment: +1 for seeming like what I want, but I don't see a model number...  This is some sort of HWIC switching module I think, just not sure which one ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what hardware you're on, but have you tried "show modules"?

Comment: Command doesn't exist for my 3825